# Getting deleted users from Active Directory using Java JNDI

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jndi

I want to get all details of AD users which are being deleted .
As per my info when users are deleted from Active Directory they are stored in        container with **CN=Deleted Objects**

Now When i search Users with searchBase = "**DC=domain, DC=local**".Everything works fine and i get data for all users with their name , mobile etc.

But when i apply searchBase ="**CN=Deleted Objects,DC=azdomain, DC=local**"  i get error as

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=Deleted Objects,DC=azdomain, DC=local'
```

what does this error means ? , Also i am not able find any post related to same issue on internet .
Please help me with this .

Comment: I believe you need to use the Deleted Object control (1.2.840.113556.1.4.417). See [How to Search for Deleted Objects in Active Directory](https://www.petri.com/deleted-objects-in-active-directory) for explanation but only using the LDP application.